# Cannot install plugin Spring Security UI

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

The following error is produced when applying changes to project structure:

```
 - Error | Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact
   org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:jar:1.0-RC3 in grailsCentral
   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the
   full trace) 
 - Error | Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not    find
   artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:jar:1.0-RC3 in   
   grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use   
   --stacktrace to see the full trace)  
 - Error | Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact
   org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:jar:1.0-RC3 in grailsCentral   
   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the 
   full trace)                
 - Error | Could not find artifact         
   org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:jar:1.0-RC3 in grailsCentral   
   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

Environment:

```
Java 1.7
Grails 2.3.8
IntelliJ IDEA 15 as IDE
```

Dependency added to BuildConfig.groovy:
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:1.0-RC3"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me with 2.3.11 - try upgrading to that (or even better, to 2.5 or 3.x, i.e. a version that's not _years_ old)

Comment: I started a new project so I had to install Spring Security Core from the beginning and now I'm getting the same error with this plugin. Tried with Grails 2.4.5 and 2.5.5 over Java 8.